# Checked the check box in ui-grid angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Using ui-grid in my project, i am getting JSON object from DB like Below

```
[
    {
        "checkbox1": {
            "fieldName": "checkbox1",
            "fieldValue": "Y"
        },
        "checkbox2": {
            "fieldName": "checkbox3",
            "fieldValue": "Y"
        },
        "checkbox3": {
            "fieldName": "checkbox3",
            "fieldValue": "N"
        }
    }
]
```

Below object is columnDef

```
[
    {
        "name": "checkbox1",
        "field": "checkbox1.fieldValue",
        "displayName": "checkbox1",
        "cellTemplate": '<input type=\"checkbox\" ng-model=\"{{COL_FIELD}}\" ng-true-value=\'Y\' ng-false-value=\'N\' />'
    },
    {
        "name": "checkbox2",
        "field": "checkbox2.fieldValue",
        "displayName": "checkbox2",
        "cellTemplate": '<input type=\"checkbox\" ng-model=\"{{COL_FIELD}}\" ng-true-value=\'Y\' ng-false-value=\'N\' />'
    },
    {
       "name": "checkbox3",
        "field": "checkbox3.fieldValue",
        "displayName": "checkbox3",
        "cellTemplate": '<input type=\"checkbox\" ng-model=\"{{COL_FIELD}}\" ng-true-value=\'Y\' ng-false-value=\'N\' />'
    }
];
```

After rendering the html, I am getting an error in the console:

> `Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.1/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7Bgrid.getCellValue(row%2Col)%7D%7D&p4=%7Bgrid.getCellValue(row%2C%col)%7D%7D`

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what it is from the error, but you must have some kind of syntax error in your html. The clue for the error is in the query string: `p0={&p1=invalid key&p2=2&p3={{grid.getCellValue(row,ol)}}&p4={grid.getCellValue(row,col)}}`... You might have misspelled `col`, or you might be missing an opening curly brace. Would help to see controller/html code, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tutorial: 201 Edit Feature](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20201%20Edit%20Feature)

try to use 'boolean' type instead of 'checkbox'

Comment: Hi @un.spike, small doubt, i am getting 1000 records from DB, in that two columns check boxes, but after service call UI is not responding properly it is struck  for 3 or 4 mins, could you please suggest any idea or any solution for this problem, Thanks in advance !

Comment: I am not able to un check the checked check box and, i am not able checked the un checked box, do you have any idea, any thing may wrong,  could please suggest.
`<input type=\"checkbox\" ng-model=\"COL_FIELD\" ng-true-value=\'"Y"\' ng-false-value=\'"N"\'/> `

Comment: set enableCellEdit  : true, in colDef

Comment: give me the plinker with your sample

Comment: Could you please look into i am sharing the [plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uMhkYg5zdBdnPFtxHjNO?p=preview), in my JSON data, filed value is true but check box value is not checked and another object cellTemplate value has link it is not updating, please help me into solve my problem and please check console log please thanks so much

Comment: working example 
http://plnkr.co/edit/xgURTDZOQ7sym97JV8I8?p=preview
double click - activate edit-mode, and after that u can change checkbox state.
if u wanna enable editing without double-click - u need define special directive for handling

Comment: Hi@un.spike, sorry asking again and again, my requirement is, it should not show the false and true , i need show directly Check box and it should not be double click, is there any example like that, could you please help me out, thanks advance !, or any idea please. and Thnks

Comment: as i said to provide hangling without double-click u need write your own directive cuz editable-mode in ui-grid by default works with double-click.
or u can try this: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/309_editable_with_cellnav

Comment: Hi @un.spike, is there any way to show directly checkbox with out showing True or False?, could you please let me know do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: wokring sample : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/gWJTEuW4GqMfa8oTaI52?p=preview

with multiple binding : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/LiSIaVKMDg6FqNg3JWKh?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Both `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` expect an expression to be passed. When you want to pass a string, it should be passed like: `ng-true-value="'Y'"`.

Example from NG docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Try correcting your cell template to fit this.